# How does partition range repair work in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

1. Will partition range repair (-pr) repairs only the primary token rages a node is responsible for or also the non-primary tokens a node is holding data?
2. If only primary tokens, then is it mandatory to run partition range repair on all nodes so that non-primary tokens also get repaired?
3. How do I find non-primary tokens a node is responsible for? The token ranges returned by nodetool ring, does it only show primary token ranges or both primary and non-primary token ranges a node is responsible for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partitioner range repair (`--partitioner-range` or `-pr`)only repair token ranges on a node where the node is the primary replica meaning it is the primary owner of the tokens (see [Manual repair in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html#ParallelvsSequentialrepair)).

Since this repair option only repairs the primary range(s) on a node, it needs to be run on all nodes in all DCs otherwise not all token ranges will get repaired.

You can find the token range ownership with `nodetool ring`. It doesn't list token ranges where the node is a secondary replica.

Partitioner range repairs (also referred to as "primary range repairs") are designed to be really efficient since it doesn't repair ranges which have already been repaired on other nodes.

Jeremiah Jordan explains this in great detail in his blog post [Apache Cassandra Maintenance and Repair](https://www.datastax.com/blog/repair-cassandra).

Patrick McFadin also explains [how repairs work and the different types of repairs in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5V5rGDTHs20&list=PL2g2h-wyI4SrHMlHBJVe_or_Ryek2THgQ&index=18) extracted from the DS210 Cassandra Operations course at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/). Cheers!

Comment: I have replaced a node in a cluster with empty data after an issue, ran rebuild to stream from another dc to avoid putting load on local dc. Running -pr repair on all nodes is going to put load on the whole cluster. How do I repair the primary and secondary tokens only on this newly added node?

Comment: You would just run a regular repair with `nodetool repair` without options. Cheers!

Comment: Would nodetool describering display secondary tokens?  would running nodetool repair with token ranges from describering cover secondary tokens?

Comment: You're trying to do it the hard way. `describering` will give you the ranges for a particular keyspace. It won't achieve the outcome you're after. A simple `nodetool repair` without any options is what you need to repair a node that was down. Cheers!